# OBTENER DATOS DE OTRA TABLA EN LA VISTA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Buen día.

Tengo 3 tablas, una se llama "Barcos", otra "Fallas" y la tercera "StatusFallas" las tablas tienen los sig. campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla "StatusFallas" solo tiene 2 registros:

1. ATENDIDA
2. EN FALLA

La pregunta es: Como hago la consulta en la vista para que si el barco tiene 1 o mas fallas que estén "EN FALLA" me indique en la vista que muestra el listado de todas las embarcaciones (Index) me ponga el texto "EN FALLA" si es que el barco tiene una falla y si no tiene fallas o esta "ATENDIDA" me indique "SIN FALLA".

Espero haberme explicado.

Cualquier apoyo se los agradeceré enormemente.

Saludos.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, agradezco tu observación